# How to make call REST using CURL

Tags: php, .htaccess, rest, curl

i am using rest api first time with curl. i create a api.php and i am calling this file using using curl and with post method. on line no 68 i am getting an error rquest varible giving notice and not getting his value 'login' with method post. this is my idea.

after curl request on page api.php rquest var value will be login and we will call login function with the help of rquest value.

Htaccess is :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php?rquest=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php [QSA,NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php [QSA,NC,L]   
</IfModule>
```

i have a parent file rest.php with class REST

api.php

```
class API extends REST {
        public $data = "";
        const DB_SERVER = "localhost";
        const DB_USER = "root";
        const DB_PASSWORD = "";
        const DB = "test";

        private $db = NULL;

        public function __construct(){
            parent::__construct();              // Init parent contructor
            $this->dbConnect();                 // Initiate Database connection
        }

        /*
         *  Database connection 
        */
        private function dbConnect(){
            $this->db = mysql_connect(self::DB_SERVER,self::DB_USER,self::DB_PASSWORD);
            if($this->db)
                mysql_select_db(self::DB,$this->db);
        }

        /*
         * Public method for access api.
         * This method dynmically call the method based on the query string
         *
         */
        public function processApi(){

            $func = strtolower(trim(str_replace("/","",$_REQUEST['rquest']))); // **line no: 68**
            if((int)method_exists($this,$func) > 0)
                $this->$func();
            else
                $this->response('',404);                // If the method not exist with in this class, response would be "Page not found".
        }

        /* 
         *  Simple login API
         *  Login must be POST method
         *  email : <USER EMAIL>
         *  pwd : <USER PASSWORD>
         */

            private function login(){
        // Cross validation if the request method is POST else it will return "Not Acceptable" status

        if($this->get_request_method() != "POST"){
             $this->response('',406);
        }

        $email = $this->_request['email'];
        $password = $this->_request['pwd'];

        // Input validations
        if(!empty($email) and !empty($password)){
            if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
                $sql = mysql_query("SELECT user_id, user_fullname, user_email FROM users WHERE user_email = '$email' AND user_password = '".$password."' LIMIT 1", $this->db);
                if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0){
                    $result = mysql_fetch_array($sql,MYSQL_ASSOC);

                    // If success everythig is good send header as "OK" and user details
                    $this->response($this->json($result), 200);
                }
                $this->response('', 204);   // If no records "No Content" status
            }
        }

        // If invalid inputs "Bad Request" status message and reason
        $error = array('status' => "Failed", "msg" => "Invalid Email address or Password");
        $this->response($this->json($error), 400);
    }

    }

    // Initiiate Library

    $api = new API;
    $api->processApi();
```

my call of api.php using curl is

index.php

```
<?php
$url = 'http://localhost/test/login/';
        $curl = curl_init();
        $curl_post_data = array(
            "pwd" => 'raj123',
            "emailaddress" => 'rajk@gmail.com',
            );
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST'); // 
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true)
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curl_post_data);
        $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        echo $curl_response;
        //$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($curl_response);

    // code adapted from Tony Spencer

?>
```

error is coming

```
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: rquest in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\test\api.php</b> on line <b>68</b><br />
```

line no 68 in api.php

```
 $func = strtolower(trim(str_replace("/","",$_REQUEST['rquest'])));
```

source link is http://www.9lessons.info/2012/05/create-restful-services-api-in-php.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Querying REST API using cURL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14079653/querying-rest-api-using-curl)

Comment: The notice is because you are trying to access an undefined index in `$_REQUEST` variable. You should first check if it exists (through `isset()` or `empty()`) or use the unrecommended "@" supressor before accessing the variable.